# Redirect outlook (Exchange) emails from "X" account to "Y" account if "x" account is disconnected

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have domain computer, with 2 users: X and Y, they have Outlook - exchange accounts and also they have webmail site for our company.

I want Y user to be signed in and X user (which must be signed out) to redirect emails to Y user's account.

Can I add this rule ? will it redirect emails even it will be singed out? how can mail process redirection if it is not logged in? 
Can webmail do that? - Remember they also have webmail

Comment: or maybe server can do that, and user account is not necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can create rules on the web mail to forward all emails from user X to Y. This rules can be processed even user X was signed out.(This is a server-side rule)
[image]